# Table checkerboard pattern using Javascript to generate class attributes

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am supposed to find a way to implement a checkerboard pattern into a function used to generate a table. I am extremely stuck on how to do this. I have searched around a lot and haven't found anything that helps. Could someone at least point me in the right direction of how to do this? I will post my html as well as js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Sliding Tile Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="grid.js"></script>
</head>


</script>
<body onload="createTable()">

<h1>Sliding Tile Puzzle</h1>


<div id="tableDiv"></div>

<h2>Finished Image</h2>
<img src="smilefinal.png" style="height:100px; width:100px;" alt="">


</body>
</html>
```

And my js that creates the table looks like

```
function createTable(){
var tableString = "<table>",
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')
    tableDiv = document.getElementById('tableDiv');
var tclass = "red";

for (row = 0; row < 3; row += 1) {

    tableString += "<tr>";

    for (col = 0; col < 3; col += 1) {

        tableString += "<td>" + "</td>";
    }
    tableString += "</tr>";
}


tableString += "</table>";
document.getElementById("tableDiv").innerHTML = tableString;
tableString.className = tclass;
body.appendChild(tableDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically looking to set **even/odd classes** dynamically. This boils down to taking the remainder of the column index divided by two—i.e. `col % 2`—and then setting the appropriate class:

```js
function createTable(n){

let tableString = "<table>";

for (row = 0; row < n; row += 1) {

    tableString += "<tr>";

    for (col = 0; col < n; col += 1) {
        tableString += `<td class="${col % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">(${row}, ${col})</td>`;
    }
    tableString += "</tr>";
}

tableString += "</table>";

const tableDiv = document.getElementById('tableDiv');
tableDiv.innerHTML = tableString;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Sliding Tile Game</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="grid.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    table {
      width: 100%;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
    }
    td {
      height: 120px;
      padding: 1em;
      border: 2px solid #470000;
    }
    .even {
      background-color: #4787f0;
    }
    .odd {
      background-color: #47f087;
    }
  </style>
</head>


</script>
<body onload="createTable(5)">

<h1>Sliding Tile Puzzle</h1>


<div id="tableDiv"></div>

<h2>Finished Image</h2>
<img src="smilefinal.png" style="height:100px; width:100px;" alt="">


</body>
</html>
```

You can also do this very simply [with CSS](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html).

Comment: Thanks! If I could have done it with CSS I would have. The professor requires it be done in javascript. One thing though. When I try to implement it, it makes each column the same color rather than making a checkerboard effect.

Comment: @UJGA Hard to tell... Have a look at the generated HTML and see if the `.even`, `.odd` classes are defined in your style sheet and if they are set on the `td` elements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript:

```css
td {
  background-color: goldenrod;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(2n + 1) > td:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
}

tr:nth-child(2n) > td:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```